# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar comillas y barras invertidas en Sed?

Tags: sed

Tengo un archivo JSON y quiero eliminar los `"": ""` y los `\n`:

```
[
  {
    "intent": "joy",
    "text": "On days when I feel close to my partner and other friends.   \nWhen I feel at peace with myself and also experience a close  \ncontact with people whom I regard greatly.",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "intent": "fear",
    "text": "Every time I imagine that someone I love or I could contact a  \nserious illness, even death.",
    "": ""
  },
...
```

Intenté resolver el problema con algunos comandos tipo:

```sh
sed s/\n// data_mood_intentified.json >data_mood_intentified2.json
```

para los `\n`, pero elimina los `n` pero deja los `\n`.

Mientras que este no funciona en absoluto:

```
sed s/"": ""/""/ data_mood_intentified.json > data_mood.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me da la sensación que quieres eliminar aquellas líneas que solamente contienen `"": ""`. Para ello, utiliza esta expresión para eliminar todo aquello que coincida con un patrón:

```
sed '/patron/d' fichero
```

Después, quieres borrar el literal `\n` de las cadenas. Lo que ocurre aquí es que al decir `sed s/\n//` Sed está interpretando `\n` como el literal salto de línea. Entonces, es importante escapar la `\` para que la reconozca como tal:

```
sed 's/\\n//g' fichero
```

Añadiendo ambos comandos tenemos:

```
sed 's#\\n##g; /^\s*"": ""/d' fichero
```

Con tu fichero:

```
$ sed 's#\\n##g; /^\s*"": ""/d' fichero
[
  {
    "intent": "joy",
    "text": "On days when I feel close to my partner and other friends.   When I feel at peace with myself and also experience a close  contact with people whom I regard greatly.",
  },
  {
    "intent": "fear",
    "text": "Every time I imagine that someone I love or I could contact a  serious illness, even death.",
  },
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Y porque utilisas `#` ?

Comment: @Marine1 para no usar siempre `/`. Son equivalentes.